# Software Center shows the name of the software in a list, but install button does not work

Tags: 11.10

Two days ago I performed a clean installation of Oneiric Ocelot on my Acer Extensa 4620. After installation I updated it first. Then I tried to install some other software packages like GIMP, Chrome, Pychess etc. But Software Center acted strangely. It shows the name of software in the list but its INSTALL button does not work. Can any one help me get out of this mess ? thanks :)

Comment: I don’t know the exact answer to this question, but first of all install Synaptic :) `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Comment: Indeed, you can use Synaptic in stead of the Software Center until this is solved. In the mean time I'd suggest you report this bug on Launchpad.

Comment: well .. thanks buddy. But how can I report this bug on launchpad??

Comment: @Lavakesh  For bug reporting, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem when installing Chrome, and I got it to work.  If I remember correctly the source of the problems was a lack of dependencies.

The command I ran was `sudo apt-get install -f`, I think.

I came upon the solution when installing something through the command line -- Ubuntu told me dependencies were missing and gave me the commands to fix it.  Hope this helps, though my problem wasn't exactly yours.

Comment: i think that is for correcting dependencies. Right ?? anyways I have installed Chrome. But I need Software Center to working fine. That's it. :)